# Excel VBA - Append .xls to filename to open file

Tags: vba, excel

I have code to open a file with a variable date, as shown below.  This code will not work without entering m.d.y.xls into the input box.  I want to only have to enter m.d.y into the input box.  Please take a look and let me know what I am missing.  Thanks!

```
Dim wbkOpen As Workbook
Dim strFilePath As String
Dim strFileName As String
strFilePath = "D:\Users\stefan.bagnato\Desktop\Daily Performance Summary\Agent Group Daily Summary "
strFileName = InputBox("Enter last Friday's date in the format M.D.Y", "Friday's Date")
Set wbkOpen = Workbooks.Open(strFilePath & strFileName, False, True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basic string concatentation:

```
strFilePath & strFileName & ".xls"
```

You should probably check to ensure the file exists, otherwise there will be an error:

```
Dim fullFileName As String
strFilePath & strFileName & ".xls"
If Dir(fullFileName) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Invalid filename!"
    Exit Sub
End If
Set wbkOpen = Workbooks.Open(fullFileName, False, True)
```

Ideally, you can avoid user-input (which is prone to error) altogether:

```
Const strFilePath As String = "D:\Users\stefan.bagnato\Desktop\Daily Performance Summary\Agent Group Daily Summary "
Dim wbkOpen As Workbook
Dim LastFridayDate As String
Dim fullFileName As String
Dim fdlg as FileDialog
LastFridayDate = Format(Date - (Weekday(Date, vbFriday) - 1), "m.d.yy")
fullFileName = strFilePath & LastFridayDate & ".xls"

If Dir(fullFileName) = "" Then
    If MsgBox("The file named " & fullFileName & " doesn't exist. Would you like to manually locate the file?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set fdlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        '## Opens the fileDialog in the normal folder where these files should exist
        fdlg.InitialFileName = strFilePath
        '## Display the fileDialog to the user
        fdlg.Show
        '## Validate the fileDialog hasn't been canceled
        If fdlg.SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
            '## Return the value of the item selected by the user
            fullFileName = fdlg.SelectedItems(1)
        Else:
            MsgBox "No file selected, exiting procedure..."
        End If
    End If
End If
Set wbkOpen = Workbooks.Open(fullFileName, False, True)
```

Of course allowing the user to manually select the file may ultimately require additional validation and/or error-handling (i.e., what if they select the wrong file? How can the program know which *date* is the *correct* date [I'd wager that it *can't*, without doing an ugly brute force loop which still makes a lot of assumptions which might not always hold] What if they select a PDF or a PPT file instead of an XLS, etc. but those points are entirely out of scope for this question.)

If you have additional follow-ups, please follow proper site etiquette and ask a new question :)

Comment: It'll be fine if the file is in use, though application.displayalerts would need to be disabled to avoid the read only dialogue.

Comment: Thanks David!  The file should always exist, so the only issue would be me mistyping the date.  Instead of doing an 'Exit Sub', how can I get it to loop back to the inputbox?

Comment: Use a `GoTo` statement or a `While` loop.

Comment: @sbagnato see revision which should avoid the need for user input :D

Comment: David, no luck.  I get file does not exist.  Now, an actual filename is "Agent Group Daily Summary 4.13.17".   However, with the holiday last week, there was no Friday.  So, I edited the code above so that vbFriday was vbThursday, but I still got a DNE error.  Ideas?

Comment: oops, in all my fanciness, I forgot to add the `.xls` to the end of the filename, I'll revise!

Comment: Revised, change to: `fullFileName = strFilePath & LastFridayDate & ".xls"` and I think that should work.

Comment: @sbagnato "with the holiday last week, there was no Friday" - uh, what? Last Friday was *Good Friday*, which last I checked *was* a Friday. If your requirement is to get the *last Friday* like you stated, then last Friday was April 14, 2017. If your requirement is to get the *last workday in a week given a business calendar*, then you have misworded your question and we're (and you're) missing data. This answer gives you exactly what you asked for and you should accept it.

Comment: Yeah, Matt, sorry but you know I did not mean there was not actually a Friday.  I meant there was no Friday file since no one worked Friday

Comment: David, looks like there still may be an issue.  As mentioned, there is no file for last Friday.  However, there is one for every day last week, as well as mon-wed this week.  However, when I run the code, it tells me no file for last Friday (which is good), and no file for Thursday.  Now, there is no file for today, because today has not ended, but why would it not grab last Thursday?  Point being, when I run it tomorrow (the day it's actually needed), if there was a Friday file, which normally there will be, it appears it will not find it...

Comment: How do you *think* you asked this code to check for last Thursday's file? :)

Comment: Hint: The `vbFriday` part of the `Weekday` function is not magically telling it to get friday's date. It's actually telling it that, for the sake of this function call, consider Friday to be the first day of the week. The `Weekday` function then returns an integer (the ordinal day of the week) which it subtracts from the `Date`.  What I would propose is, if the file is not found, you should modify code to have the user manually select the file. I'll revise that shortly.

Comment: Hm, good point.  Well, I edited the LastFriday snippet into 5 different snippets.  Including extra code added in, here is the "Thursday" code:      ThursdayDate = Format(Date - (Weekday(Date, vbThursday) - 1), "m.d.yy")
    fullFileNameThursday = strFilePath & ThursdayDate & ".xls"
    If Dir(fullFileNameThursday) = "" Then
        MsgBox "File for Thursday doesn't exist!"
        GoTo ExitThursday
    End If
    Set wbkThursday = Workbooks.Open(fullFileNameThursday, False, True)
    Call BasicDailySummary
    ...............
    wbkThursday.Close SaveChanges:=False
ExitThursday:

Comment: Please consider that it is nearly impossible to read multi-line code in comments here. You almost certainly do not want to be configuring a separate code for each day of the week, because how will the program know which day of the week it should be looking for.

Comment: Also, have you debugged this expression `Format(Date - (Weekday(Date, vbThursday) - 1), "m.d.yy") ` because if you had, you would see that it is not doing what you think it's doing (it's actually returning *today's* date, which is why you're getting "file not found" message.

Comment: FYI: to get thursday last, you'd need to: `Format(Date - (Weekday(Date, vbFriday) ), "m.d.yy") `, but don't. Use the revision above which allows the user to select the file from the folder. It's much cleaner.

Comment: David, I will test that code to see what it does.  My end goal is to open each of 5 days worth of files (last Friday, this Monday, ect., this Thursday), grab a few cells of data, and then close the files.  One larger section of code does make more sense than 5 smaller ones, one for each day, but I had not figured out how to do that part.  Once the entire script is done, the plan is to only run this Friday mornings; it is while testing that I am doing it on days such as today.

Comment: If you get stuck, please ask a separate question. The scope of this question is already well beyond the original intent, which was "how do I concatenate strings in VBA". It should be relatively easy to build a loop to create the 7 filenames (e.g., `"4.14.17", "4.15.17", ..., "4.20.17"` and then you can just use those in the macro.