# Excel VBA - Find file with variable name (weekday function)

Tags: vba, excel, date

I have a script that, among other things, loads files with variable file names corresponding to dates.  It can load dates within the last 7 days fine, however, I need it to load dates past that.

The script will be run on Friday mornings, and I need it to pull the entire week, plus entire previous week.  Currently, it will pull the previous Friday (7 days ago) up through the previous day (Thursday).

What I need is the correct code to get it to pull last Monday through last Thursday.

The code to pull last Monday is below.  I have tried changing Date - 1 to Date - 2, but that is not right.  I know that vbMonday is supposed to correspond to a date within the last 7 days (if I understand correctly.  Probably a simple thing I am missing, but no option seems to work.

(FYI all variables are declared, just omitted so it is easier to see what is happening)

```
LastMondayDate = Format(Date - (Weekday(Date - 1, vbMonday)), "m.d.yy")
fullFileNameLastMonday = strFilePath & LastMondayDate & ".xls"
If Dir(fullFileNameLastMonday) = "" Then
    MsgBox "File for last Monday doesn't exist!"
    GoTo ExitLastMonday
End If
Set wbkLastMonday = Workbooks.Open(fullFileNameLastMonday, False, True)
.......Do stuff.......
wbkLastMonday.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

ExitLastMonday:

Comment: So the difference between Friday and last Monday is 11 days, correct? You can use `Format(DateAdd("d",-11,Date),"m.d.yy")`.

Comment: DateDiff is also a very useful function.

Comment: Kyle, my only concern with settings exact numbers like that is if I run on a different day for some reason (for instance testing it today), then 11 days ago of course is not a Monday.

Comment: Why dont you use a select case on Weekday(Now()) and do date math based on what today is? More dynamic and cricuvents having to rewrite code everytime you run into a new scenario

Comment: Doug, so I make sure I understand you correctly, could you provide an example?

Comment: seems like it would be a lot easier to just use VBA to display a `FileDialog` and allow the user to open the file. You're continually asking variants of essentially the same question (see also: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521067/excel-vba-open-files-with-variable-dates-filenames), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43497439/excel-vba-append-xls-to-filename-to-open-file)), which is: "What is the simple solution that will handle any possible exception?" and the answer is basically "There isn't one". Use proper error handling and deal with exceptional cases manually if needed.

Comment: *I know that vbMonday is supposed to correspond to a date within the last 7*. No, [you haven't been paying attention](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43521621/1467082) because I explained that in your other question and [also in a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43497439/excel-vba-append-xls-to-filename-to-open-file#comment74091822_43497492) on your *other* question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Weekday function returns a number between 1 and 7 representing the 7 days of the week. `Weekday(Date, vbMonday)` specifies that Monday will be the day which has the number 1, the first day of the week. `Weekday(Date - 1, vbMonday)` will always specify a Monday. To specify another day change the `-1` in the formula.

`Date - Weekday(Date - 1, vbMonday)` specifies the same day for 7 days in a row because as the date advances (+ 1 every day) so does the Weekday which is subtracted from it. From Tuesday until Monday next week it will specify the current week's Monday. Then it will jump to the next Monday.

In order to capture a Monday which is earlier, just modify the date component. `Date - 7 - Weekday(Date - 1, vbMonday)`  will do exactly the same as just described but 7 days further in the past.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
Public Sub LoveMondays()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 15
        Debug.Print DateAdd("ww", i * -1, Date - (Weekday(Date, vbMonday) - 1))
    Next i

End Sub
```

It gives the dates of the last 15 Mondays.
Then, if applicable, a function of the Debug.Print with `i` as an input variable would be useful.

E.g.:

```
Public Function MondaysWeekBack(lngWeekBack As Long) As Date
    MondaysWeekBack = DateAdd("ww", lngWeekBack * -1, Date - (Weekday(Date, vbMonday) - 1))
End Function
```

Thus for the current week, you can get the Monday like this:
`MondaysWeekBack(0)`
and for the previous `MondaysWeekBack(1)`.

Here is the Microsoft reference of `DateAdd` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcxe65wz(v=vs.90).aspx

Edit: As suggested in the comment by @Robin Mackenzie, the function could be extended to make the day a variable as well. Like this:

```
Public Function WeekdayWeekBack(lngWeekBack As Long, _ 
                       Optional lngWeekday As Long = 2) As Date

    WeekdayWeekBack = DateAdd("ww", lngWeekBack * -1, Date - (Weekday(Date, lngWeekday) - 1))
End Function
```

Then if we want the last Sunday, we should go like this `WeekdayWeekBack(0,1)` or `WeekdayWeekBack(0,vbSunday)`. Monday is by default, thus `WeekdayWeekBack(0)` would give us the last Monday.

Comment: You could extend that function to give OP to allow for variable days: `Public Function WeekdayWeekBack(lngWeekBack As Long, lngWeekday As Long) As Date:   WeekdayWeekBack = DateAdd("ww", lngWeekBack * -1, Date - (Weekday(Date, lngWeekday) - 1)): End Function` and then use it like: `Debug.Print WeekdayWeekBack(2, vbThursday)`

Answer (score 1):

Here try this

```
Private Sub that()

    Dim LastDate As Date
    Dim NewDate As Date
    Dim path As String
    Dim filename As String


        Select Case Weekday(Now())
            Case Is = 2
                LastDate = Format(DateAdd("d", -14, Date), "mm-dd-yyyy")
            Case Is = 3
                LastDate = Format(DateAdd("d", -14, Date), "mm-dd-yyyy")
            Case Is = 4
                LastDate = Format(DateAdd("d", -15, Date), "mm-dd-yyyy")
            Case Is = 5
                LastDate = Format(DateAdd("d", -16, Date), "mm-dd-yyyy")
            Case Is = 6
                LastDate = Format(DateAdd("d", -18, Date), "mm-dd-yyyy")
        End Select

        NewDate = LastDate + 11
        path = "" & "\"
        filename = Dir(path & "*.xl??")

         Do While Len(filename) > 0
            this = Mid(filename, InStrRev(filename, "\") + 1, InStrRev(filename, "."))
            this = Left(this, InStr(this, ".") - 1)
            If CDate(this) >= LastDate And CDate(this) <= NewDate Then
                ' do your stuff
            End If
         Loop
End Sub
```

This can be run any day of the week and gets the last two previous weeks. The section where it says "'do your stuff" is where you'd put the body of your action code. I did some string manipulation, forced them to date values with a check that sees if the current file is within the date range you want to check for. This isnt tested but I am 100% on it working. Also, you'll need to set the path variable, but i am sure its 100%==to strFilePath.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to change the code from LastMondayDate, LastTuesdayDate, LastWednesdayDate to something much easier:  FirstDayToGet.  Please note below is only the logic.  This logic will open all the date-files you need from the starting date to the current date - or alternatively you could add an ending date if current date is too broad

```
Sub logicOnlyNotActualCode()
FirstDayToGet = datepicker or textbox value date or cell value date
toooooday = date() ' or some end date

for I = FirstDayToGet to FirstDayToGet + (toooooday - FirstDayToGet)
    run get_date_report(FirstDayToGet)
    FirstDayToGet = dateAdd("d",1,FirstDayToGet)
next i
End Sub
```

And your function would look something like:

```
function get_date_report(FirstDayToGet as date)
dim get_report as string
    get_report = strFilePath & Format(FirstDayToGet , "m.d.yy")  & ".xls"

Do events
End function
```

Answer (score 0):

This function returns the date values from `numDays` days ago, up through *yesterday's* date, inclusive. It does not account for exceptions like holidays or weekends, etc.  What you should do is use this function to build the filenames, and then use the `Dir` function to test for presence of the file, and (obviously) if the file not exist, do not attempt to open or process it, just move on to the next iteration.

```
Function GetFileNames(numDays As Long, optional dFormat as String = "m.d.yy")
'Function returns a string array (len = numDays) of formatted date values
'beginning from numDays days ago, until yesterday's date.
ReDim filenames(1 To numDays) As String
Dim LastDate As Date, i As Long

LastDate = Date 'Returns TODAY's date
'Use DateAdd function to calculate the last numDays:
For i = 1 To numDays
    filenames(i) = Format(DateAdd("d", -(numDays) + i - 1, LastDate), dFormat)
Next

GetFileNames = filenames
End Function
```

Here is a way you can test it:

```
Sub TestMe()
Dim a
a = GetFileNames(1) 'Should return an array of len=1, yesterday's date only
MsgBox a(1) 
a = GetFileNames(14) 'Should return an array of len=14, fourteen days prior to and including Yesterday

End Sub
```

[image]

This is how you get all 14 filenames without creating 14 variable/workbook objects:

```
Dim dateVals 
dateVals = GetFileNames(14)
```

Now, do something with the array (like open the corresponding workbooks and process them somehow:

```
Dim val, Dim wb as Workbook
For Each val in DateVals
    If Dir(strFilePath & val & ".xls") <> "" Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strFilePath & val & ".xls")
        'Do something with the workbook
        wb.Close
    End If
Next
```